# Yii1: View data from another table

Tags: php, yii

I am working in a Yii application. I need help regarding fetching data from another table and show it inside a table in a page where I want to show.

Here is Defect table columns:

```
id,
vehicle_id,
vehicle_name,
etc..
```

and Defectdetail table columns:

```
id,
defect_id,  <- defect_id comes from defect table id
defect_detail,
etc..
```

Here Defect can have multiple Defectdetail. Defectdetail have one defect. 
So here relation declared in Defect table

```
public function relations(){
    return array(
        'defectdetail'=>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Defectdetail', 'defect_id'),
    )
}
```

and in Defectdetail

```
public function relations(){
    return array(
        'defects'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Defects', 'defect_id'),
    );
}
```

In my Defect index page, there is a TbGridView table. which shows Defects list. What I want is that in my TbGridView, there will be a column in each row which will show multiple Defectdetail (**from *defect_detail* column**) per defects but seperated by commas. 
Here is the TbGridView in index page>>>

```
<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(
      'type'=>'striped bordered condensed',
      'id'=>'defects-grid',
      'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,

    'columns'=>array(
        array(
            'name' => 'id',
            'type'=>'raw',
            'value' => 'CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($data->id),array("view","id"=>$data->id))',
        ),
        'vehicle_id',
        'vehicle_name',
        ''  <--- Here is where I want to show multiple defectdetails seperated by commas
```

I will be grateful if anyone helps me. I am trying to do it but couldn't understand how to do it.Thank you.

Comment: `$data->defectdetail->defect_detail`
 , i don't remember correctly, but you can access relational table data with relation name -> column name

Comment: I know , I can access relational data that way but it returned an array so nothing was shown. Anyway I figured out the way to do it. Thanks.